# Почему не срабатывает экранирование?

Tags: sass, scss, gulp-sass

Оригинальный кейс. Если нужно, то я добавлю `map` для полной картины, хотя я не вижу в этом смысла.

```
@each $name, $str in $icomoon {
    [class^="icon-#{$name}"]:before, [class*="icon-#{$name}"]:before {
        content: unquote("\"") + unquote(str-insert($str, "\\", 1)) + unquote("\"");
    }
}
```

**Результат:** `content: "\hey";`

1. **В этом случае я использую вокруг [интерполяции](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/sassscript/interpolyatsiya.html) `" "`.**

   > scss

   ```
   content: "#{unquote(str-insert(hey, "\\", 1))}";
   ```

   > css

   ```
   content: "\\hey";
   ```
2. **Противоположный случай**

   > scss

   ```
   content: #{unquote(str-insert(hey, "\\", 1))};
   ```

   > css

   ```
   content: \hey;
   ```

Смущает, что в основном кейсе нужно использовать метод `unquote` ради интерполяции.

Comment: я не совсем понял вопрос: в чем именно он заключается? какой результат в итоге ты хочешь получить?

Comment: как в основном кейсе, но меня смущает, что для скобочек нужно задействовать 2 раза метод unquote

Answer (score 1):

Код приведённый в оригинальном кейсе показался мне довольно громоздким.
Потому как [unquote](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method) удаляет кавычки из строки.

Если вы ищите более простой вариант и хотите избавится от частого использования фукнции `unquote` посмотрите на код ниже:

```
$icomoon: (
  icon-hey: hey
);

@each $name, $str in $icomoon {
  [class^="icon-#{$name}"]:before, [class*="icon-#{$name}"]:before {
    content: #{'"\\' + $str + '"'};
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за простой вариант, но меня больше гложет, почему так происходит у меня в примере)